# Execute mysql "create function" statement with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function, create-function

I want to run the following `mysql` create function statement from PHP:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `myFunc`(`instring` varchar(4000)) RETURNS int(11)
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE position int;
    ....here comes function logic
    RETURN position;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But I get this mysql error:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER'

What can I do? Can I execute create statement without DELIMITER keyword?

Comment: **Don't use the mysql_** functions. They're deprecated for a while now. The two libraries that are still maintained are mysqli and PDO.

Comment: MySQL is not deprecated. It is the `mysql_*` family of functions that are. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant. Edited

Comment: Bingo (credit to google): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311141/how-to-execute-mysql-command-delimiter

Comment: I am using mysqli, but that's just an adapter. Sql client is still mysql.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You most likely do not need the `DELIMTER` command. That belongs to MySQL-centric client programs.

Please try with plain old semicolons:

```
if (!$mysqli->query("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS p") ||
    !$mysqli->query("CREATE PROCEDURE p(IN id_val INT) BEGIN INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES(id_val); END;")) {
    echo "Stored procedure creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

and let PHP worry about delimiting

## CAVEAT

I got the above code from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

Comment: ... "and let PHP worry about delimiting" <-- saved my day :D