# Add mysql trigger with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, triggers

Here is my trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER vf_update_checksum AFTER INSERT ON `vf_params` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   SET @last_param_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
   SET @object_id = (SELECT p.object_id
                                FROM vf_params as p
                            WHERE p.id = @last_param_id
                            LIMIT 1);

   SET @object_type = (SELECT ot.name
                                    FROM vf_objects as o
                            LEFT JOIN vf_objectTypes as ot ON o.object_type_id = ot.object_type_id
                                WHERE o.object_id = @object_id
                                    LIMIT 1);

   SET @params = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(CAST(p.int_value AS CHAR), CAST(p.float_value AS CHAR), p.text_value, p.array_value, CAST(p.reference_value AS CHAR)) SEPARATOR '') AS VALUE 
                    FROM vf_params as p
                        WHERE p.object_id = @object_id
                            GROUP BY 'all'
                                LIMIT 1);

   SET @object_heap = CONCAT(@object_type, @params);
   SET @chksm = MD5(@object_heap);

   UPDATE vf_objects as o SET o.checksum = @chksm WHERE o.object_id = @object_id;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

And I'm tried to place this code into strign and execute it with `PDO`, but it fails to create trigger.
I think, the problem is in `DELIMITER //`, but it can't be created without it (or it can be?).
Also I tried `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 0);` and than `$pdo->exec()`...the same thing.

What is the way to create such trigger with `PDO`??

Comment: Does this code work when executed directly?

Comment: @infomaniac yes, works fine

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5314879/385265

Comment: @infomaniac yes. as you can see, my trigger has many lines, that must be separated. if i don't use `DELIMITER`, mysql determines only part, before `LAST_INSERT_ID();` and the other part will be throwed off