# How to change mysql Delimiter inside Kohana framework during call one model method?

Tags: mysql, kohana, delimiter, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

I have one method that must create mysql procedure, and run it. The problem is to change delimiter

```
public function doSomeThing(){
    $run = array();
    $run[] = DB::query(null, "DELIMITER $$");
    //... here we continue of pushing more commands
    /**
     * @var Database_Query[] $run
     */
    foreach($run as $command){
        $command->execute();
    }
}
```

I see exception:

> Database_Exception [ 1064 ]: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$' at line 1 [ DELIMITER $$ ]

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to execute mysql command DELIMITER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311141/how-to-execute-mysql-command-delimiter)

Comment: [This post](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/4784/how-to-do-a-mysqli-multi_query/p1) from the official Kohana forum might help as well (tl;dr: `multi_query` is not supported by Kohana)

Comment: yep! You was right! It' works without delimiter. Please, post a reply as "delimiter is not mysql command, it's command of shell. Try to use array of queries ignoring delimiter" to I can mark it as solution for my question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311141/how-to-execute-mysql-command-delimiter), you cannot use the `DELIMITER` via PHP as it is a command line statement. Just leave it out and use an array of queries (Kohana sadly [does not support multiple queries](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/4784/how-to-do-a-mysqli-multi_query/p1) via one call to the `DB`)