# Multiple Create Trigger query in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, innodb

I am trying to run the following SQL string in PDO. I can confirm that the code does execute in MySQL directly but running it in PHP PDO it throws an error.

I understand that the `DELIMITER $$` is not available on the PDO interface. And according to [how to execute mysql command DELIMITER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311141/how-to-execute-mysql-command-delimiter) it should be fine to just leave the delimiter out of the query.

**QUERY STRING:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `M5_tblMVTransactionVat_VatInsert` AFTER INSERT ON `M2_tblVatRevisions`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  UPDATE M5_tblMVTransactionVat
  SET M5_tblMVTransactionVat.vatID = 1;

END

CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `M5_tblMVTransactionVat_VatUpdate` AFTER UPDATE ON `M2_tblVatRevisions`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  UPDATE M5_tblMVTransactionVat
  SET M5_tblMVTransactionVat.vatID = 2;

END
```

Run via either a simple PDO::exec or PDOStatement::prepare (with PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = 1) causes an error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE
DEFINER=CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `M5_tblMVTransactionVat_VatUpdate` AFTER
UPD' at line 8
```

I have confirmed that running only one Create Trigger at a time via PDO does not cause the same error and the trigger is created successfully.
.

How do I execute multiple create trigger queries on a PDO connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't execute multiple statements at a time.

There is no reason to do so, and [it causes problems if you try](http://xkcd.com/327).

The former Director of Engineering for MySQL once told me, *there is no reason for multi_query to exist, it can only do harm* (that's my paraphrasing).

It's simpler and safer to execute each CREATE TRIGGER statement in its own call to `PDO::exec()`.

Comment: Okay, so then if I wanted to apply a large amount of create triggers on a database via PHP PDO as an database initialization sequence, it would require me to put them into different files, or write my own delimiter/parser?

Comment: Yes. How do you think the `mysql` client does it?

Comment: I thought it was via the MySQL CLI, which has a builtin parser? Edit: now that you mention it I see things like DELETE VIEWS are listed as separate statements on the history.

Comment: The client has a very simple parser: It reads until the DELIMITER string, then it sends what it has read to the server to be executed as a single statement. Then it reads until the next DELIMITER and repeats the process.

Comment: Just seemed silly to have have to write my own one if its something so generally used.

Comment: Then write it as a reusable PHP package to run SQL scripts, and release it as an open-source product, so other people don't have to reinvent this wheel. So far, I've never seen one that actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

You want a bunch of initialization stuff in a file?  Then why bother with PHP; do

```
mysql ... -e "source foo.sql"
```

Ok, you do want PHP to run things?  Then do this from php:

```
execcute('mysql ... -e "source foo.sql"');
```

But, you had better button down the hatches -- this would be a wonderful way for a hacker to wreak havoc.

Comment: seems like this is an easier approach than writing my own client to interpret an SQL file. Thanks! It's a solution to my problem but not 'technically' a answer to my question. So I will be selecting the 'You can't' answer as the answer from bill-karwin

Comment: @EatonEmmerich - Many questions on this forum fail to state the _original_ problem, but only state the problem that occurred just before hitting a brick wall.  (I do like, and agree with, Bill's answer.)