# SQL Syntax Error When Sending From Script

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I send this SQL from a PHP script I get a SQL syntax error, however, if I run it from phpMyAdmin it works as I expect it to.

The SQL:

```
DELIMITER $
    CREATE TRIGGER update_listing_count
    AFTER UPDATE ON `items`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE `listings` SET units = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `items` WHERE listingid = NEW.listingid) WHERE id = NEW.listingid;
        UPDATE `listings` SET unitsSold = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `items` WHERE listingid = NEW.listingid AND sold = true) WHERE id = NEW.listingid;
    END$
    DELIMITER ;
```

The PHP:

```
$conn = DBConnection();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELIMITER $
    CREATE TRIGGER update_listing_count
    AFTER UPDATE ON `items`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE `listings` SET units = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `items` WHERE listingid = NEW.listingid) WHERE id = NEW.listingid;
        UPDATE `listings` SET unitsSold = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `items` WHERE listingid = NEW.listingid AND sold = true) WHERE id = NEW.listingid;
    END$
    DELIMITER ;");
    $stmt->execute();
```

The error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $ CREATE TRIGGER update_listing_count AFTER UPDATE ON `items` ' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\marketplace.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\marketplace.php(25): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\marketplace.php on line 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you can't use DELIMETER ON pdo...

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969269/13113663

Comment: If the answer is to link to another question, this would normally just be closed as a duplicate.  As it stands this question/answer doesn't provide anything new and can just clog up the already large pool of resources on SO.